# Is there a way to prevent rows on having more elements than other rows when using masonry.js?

Tags: css, jquery-masonry

https://codepen.io/codepen_user_123/pen/xxgXYqY

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnHeight: 1360,
  gutterHeight: 120;
});
```

So I use this to create a non-masonry type grid, but the issue is that sometimes I get two elements on the same instead of one.

The image below describes what I am looking for:

[image]

You see there are only 5 elements on each row, in the codepen provided, some rows have more elements than others because there's enough space to fit more than 1 elements on certain columns of the row, so is there a way to prevent this from happening? I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give you a bit of a strange answer... but you may not even need masonry (and JS and jQuery for that matter) for what you are trying to achieve. I believe a plain HTML and CSS answer is appropriate in this case. There is this relatively new feature in CSS called [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids). Here's an example close to what you want. All the main code for the layout is right here.

```css
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

And here's a more full example containing styles similar to your above image:

```css
.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 12px;
  display: grid;
}


/* unnecessary stylistic changes below here */
.grid {
  --color-1: rgb(252,151,36);
  --color-2: rgb(240,67,60);
  --color-3: rgb(97,125,138);
}


body {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(56,64,70)
}

.grid > * {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.7em;
}

.grid > *:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
}

.grid :nth-child(3n + 2) {
  background-color: var(--color-2);
}

.grid > *:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: var(--color-3);
}

.grid > *:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  height: 75px;
}


.grid :nth-child(4n + 2) {
  height: 150px;
}

.grid :nth-child(4n + 3) {
  height: 50px;
}

.grid :nth-child(4n) {
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: P.S. feel free to ask me any questions about how to do anything here in the comments. I can't guarantee I'll answer right away, but I'll try to eventually.

Comment: Does the solution work for any resolution? I had an issue with horizontal ordering.

Comment: @caesar unsure what you mean could you provide a minimal example where it fails and explain a bit on how the horizontal ordering is an issue? (As an exmple of a different resolution of the above example here is a different wider page size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67007421/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-rows-on-having-more-elements-than-other-rows-when-usin/67008232#67008232)

Comment: Ah, nevermind, when I was using masonry without the masonry.js library I had an ordering issue.